# On Document Ready, Trigger a function that is binded by a click

Tags: jquery

I have a function in a JavaScript like so:

```
$("#table-filters li").click(function(){ *** Lots of stuff here...
});
```

What I would like to happen is when the page loads, to one-time, run that function. Something contained in:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
});
```

Suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

```
$(function(){ 
  $("#table-filters li")
    .click(function(){
      // Lots of stuff here...
    })
    .slice(0,1).click();
});
```

Comment: +1 For chaining, and a creative use of `slice`. Though this is very clear, I just want to note that `.click()` without any parameters also triggers the click event.

Comment: @Dough, aaah, yeah I forgot about click(), probably because when triggering directly I usually bind to some custom event as well as click and trigger that custom event instead of click, so that other stuff bound to click won't trigger. But less is less and we like less, so I changed it.

Comment: @svinto Oh yeah, I do that to. The custom namespaces are killer!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$("#table-filters li").trigger("click");
```

Comment: That doesn't work. It appears that clicks ALL the LI's in the ul. Is there a way to just trigger a SINGLE click for the FIRST LI?

Comment: ok got it!
 $("#table-filters li:first").trigger("click");

Thanks for the tip

Answer (score -3):

`$("#table-filters li:first").trigger("click");`

Comment: Your question didn't say you wanted only to click the first `li`. And two other users have already provided excellent answers. Accept one of theirs please.